# How execute annotation processing in gradle separatly from build task

Tags: java, gradle

I want to run QueryDsl Q-type generation in a separate task. I want that Q-type classes not to be created in a regular compileJava task, but the compiler sees the AnnotationProcessor in the classpath and creates them itself. I tried nulling the annotationProcessorPath, but then I couldn't restore its configuration in a separate task.
May be is it possible to exclude somehow dependencies of subtasks from the classpath?

```
compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = null
}

tasks.register('generateQTypes'){
    group 'build'
    description 'Generate Q-Type classes with QueryDsl library'
    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor(
                'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4:jpa',
                'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2',
                'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.1')
    }
    compileJava {
        options.annotationProcessorPath = classpath
    }
}
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?Thanks in advance!

Comment: it was bad code, without lazy initialization and TaskAction body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following solution

```
class QTypeGenerator extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    addDependencies() {
        project.dependencies {
            annotationProcessor(
                    'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4:jpa',
                    'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2',
                    'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.1')
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("generateQTypeClasses", QTypeGenerator) {
    group('build')
    description('Generate Q-type classes by queryDsl in build directory with default path')
    finalizedBy('compileJava')
    doLast {
        println("Q-types classes will gererated and stored in ${compileJava.options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory}")
    }
}
```